# Send new urls to selenium once the process is running

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium to scrape some sites, but I need to implement this on-demand for specific URLs on the same domain. This sites require to log, so my idea for this is to login once in the site: www.my_site.com, and keep the instance running when a request for a new site arrives.

E.G. Lets say the site is linkedin:

```
1) Load the page
```

[image]

```
2) Restore the session using the cookies:
```

[image]

```
3) A request for the profile arrives: christian-tutiven
```

[image]

```
4) Wait for a new request to arrive.
```

How can this be accomplished on selenium or a similar tool?

EDIT:

The purpose of this, (with another sites) is to have it as an API. 
On  my service (site A), someone request so see the full profile of "Carlos" on LinkedIn (Side B) I send this request to selenium with the user name, and selenium should load the profile and return the data to me. 
I'm doing it this way because is necessary to be logedin in order to see the full profile, and is not an option to make all the process from scrach for each request, because it will take too much waiting time.

Comment: read the request, store the variable... add "www.my_site.com/id/" to the beginning...use Selenium to .get the variable.   I think you'd need to post more details to get something specific here.  Details of this "request" and any markup that appears... and markup for a profile.

Comment: @pcalkins I just edited the question with more details.

Comment: You can just automate the login instead of using cookies there.... the html markup would be more important than the screenshots... the "request" part in particular.  I'm still not clear on what that is.  Is this a notification in LinkedIn?

Comment: This really sounds like a task that should be done from a server and not through a browser interface.  Ideally you'd want to learn LinkedIn's API for this... if they have one.

Comment: Here's the page for the API:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Comment: @pcalkins Yeah, the idea is to develop a sort of API. But is not for linkedin, this is just and example, and the site does not have an API

Comment: @pcalkins I just put a more detailed description at the end of the question. Regarding the login, the problem is that that way is very likely to have captchas in the middle.

Comment: well the implementation is dependent on the site and it's markup... I'd say only use Selenium if you need a browser to navigate the site.  You can run something that sends requests without getting bogged down with a browser interface.

Comment: @pcalkins I would use a headless browser, its just that selenium solves the issue of restoring the session quite easy

Comment: OK, so basically you'd want to use an expected condition wait inside a loop... (create a button outside of the browser you can click to abort it.) Once the request is received create the URL var open a tab, switch driver to new tab, go to the url, scrape it, save the data, close the tab and switch driver back to original tab.

Comment: @pcalkins Yeah, something like that, except that the main app and the scrapper are running in different machines.